# Black Screen trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows

Tags: installation, dual-boot

I have  Fujitsu AH532 Laptop with windows 8 on it, I tried installing the ubuntu 13.10 on it, I make it to the try ubuntu or install ubuntu page easily,(live mode works fine) when i click on the installing and install ubuntu inside windows 8, the screen goes black saying all processes are terminated and then shutsdown when i press enter. I have tried installing from flash drive and from DVD.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Dual booting with windows can be tricky.

Here is a guide to show you the basics of partitioning and prepping before install.

[Ubuntu Windows 8 Dual-Boot](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html)